# SwiftUI : Converting Int16 to String

Tags: swiftui

I'm learning Swift and I have problems displaying the result of a PickerTextField as an String instead of an Int16...
I'm Using an Int16 because I want to save it to core data...

To pick the Int16 I'm using a pickertextfield:

```
struct PickerTextField: UIViewRepresentable{

private let textField = UITextField()
private let pickerView = UIPickerView()
private let helper = Helper()

var data: [String]
var placeholder: String

@Binding var lastSelectedIndex: Int16?


func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
    self.pickerView.delegate = context.coordinator
    self.pickerView.dataSource = context.coordinator

    self.textField.placeholder = self.placeholder
    self.textField.inputView = self.pickerView
    
    //Configure Accesory View
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self.helper, action: #selector(self.helper.doneButtonAction))
    toolbar.setItems([flexibleSpace, doneButton], animated: true)
    doneButton.tintColor = UIColor.black
    self.textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar

    self.helper.doneButtonTapped = {
        if self.lastSelectedIndex == nil {
            self.lastSelectedIndex = 0
        }
        self.textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    
    
    return self.textField
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
    if let lastSelectedIndex = self.lastSelectedIndex {
        uiView.text = self.data[Int(lastSelectedIndex)]
    }
}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    return Coordinator(data: self.data) { (index) in
        self.lastSelectedIndex = Int16(index)
    }
}

class Helper {
    
    public var doneButtonTapped: (() -> Void)?
    @objc func doneButtonAction() {
        self.doneButtonTapped?()
    }
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    private var data: [String]
    private var didSelectItem: ((Int) -> Void)?

    init(data: [String], didSelectItem: ((Int) -> Void)? = nil) {
    self.data = data
    self.didSelectItem = didSelectItem
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return self.data.count

    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return self.data[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        self.didSelectItem?(row)
    }




    }
}
```

And this is the UI to pick a from the pickertextfield...

```
struct PickerView: View {

@State private var lastSelectedIndex: Int16?


var body: some View {
    VStack{
        // Text...
        Text("Choose a Color!")
        //Picker...
        PickerTextField(data: ["Red", "Green", "Blue"], placeholder: "Choose a Color!", lastSelectedIndex: self.$lastSelectedIndex)
    }
}
```

}

Is there a way to convert this 'lastSelectedIndex'(Int16) to an String?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2997127-init

Comment: since `lastSelectedIndex` is Optional, you could use `String(lastSelectedIndex ?? 0)`, to convert it to a String.

Comment: @workingdog thank you! I tried to implement the following in to my code: "var lastSelectedIndexString = String(lastSelectedIndex ?? 0)" ... but I came up with the following error: "Cannot use instance member 'lastSelectedIndex' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"

Comment: yes, as the error says, you cannot use `lastSelectedIndex` to initialise `lastSelectedIndexString` at that level. You can do this in `init()` or commonly in `.onAppear {...}` for example. I recommend you read again Apple's SwiftUI Tutorials https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
struct PickerView: View {
    @State private var lastSelectedIndex: Int16? = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 55) {
            // for testing
            Text("lastSelectedIndex = " + String(lastSelectedIndex ?? 0)) // <--- here
            // Text...
            Text("Choose a Color!")
            //Picker...
            PickerTextField(data: ["Red", "Green", "Blue"],
                            placeholder: "Choose a Color!",
                            lastSelectedIndex: $lastSelectedIndex)
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
struct PickerView: View {
    @State private var lastSelectedIndex: Int16? = 0
    @State private var lastSelectedIndexString = "0"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 55) {
            // for testing
            Text("lastSelectedIndex = " + String(lastSelectedIndex ?? 0)) // <-- here
            // Text...
            Text("Choose a Color!")
            //Picker...
            PickerTextField(data: ["Red", "Green", "Blue"],
                            placeholder: "Choose a Color!",
                            lastSelectedIndex: $lastSelectedIndex)
        }.onAppear {
            lastSelectedIndexString = String(lastSelectedIndex ?? 0) // <-- here
        }
    }
}
```

Or, using a computed property, such as:

```
struct PickerView: View {
    @State private var lastSelectedIndex: Int16? = 0
    
    var lastSelectedIndexString: String {  // <-- here
        String(lastSelectedIndex ?? 0)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 55) {
            // for testing
            Text("lastSelectedIndexString = " + lastSelectedIndexString)  // <-- here
            // Text...
            Text("Choose a Color!")
            //Picker...
            PickerTextField(data: ["Red", "Green", "Blue"],
                            placeholder: "Choose a Color!",
                            lastSelectedIndex: $lastSelectedIndex)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help... It stilll give me an error "Extra argument 'lastSelectedIndex' in call" but you've already helped me enough, I don't want to waste your time.. :D I should go back to some tutorials and read your recommended tutorial...

Comment: all my code above work well for me. Can you show where you get this error in my code?

Comment: I just went through everything again and realized I had a typo...
now everything works! thank you so much you saved my day!! :)